# Using XeLaTeX and xeCJK, why does 円 not render?

Tags: xetex, cjk, xecjk, japanese

I'm using XeLaTeX on macOS 10.15.4 and the xeCJK package to write text in Japanese. Everything works fine, except for the kanji character "円". When I use this character, it gets rendered as an uppercase "F" with a box around it. When I copy it, it looks like this: �

This is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{fontspec,xeCJK,graphicx,tikz}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
円
\end{document}
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: The character is likely not in the font being used. I will look.

Answer (score 1):

I would use explicit `\setCJKmainfont`, `\setCJKsansfont`, and `\setCJKsansfont` directives to set the "serif", "sans serif", and "monospaced" fonts for the document.

Of course, if your document requires the use of a single "sans serif"-type font, be sure to load it via `\setmainfont`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xeCJK} % loads 'fontspec' automatically
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK JP} % just for this example
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Sans CJK JP Light}
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK SC}[Language=Japanese]
\begin{document}
円 \textsf{円} \texttt{円}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's interesting information, thank you. However, I get the following error: Package fontspec Error: The font "Noto Serif CJK JP" cannot be found.

Comment: @Stephan - The Noto fonts are not included by default in most (all?) TeX distributions. However, they may be [downloaded and installed free of charge](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/install/). Seven [7!] font weights each are available for `NotoSansCJKjp-*` and `NotoSerifCJKjp-*`, and 2 font weights (`Regular` and `Bold`) for `NotoSansMonoCJKjp-*`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error thanks to the comment: wrong font. Adding

```
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
```

fixes it.